# Create 2 arrays of random integers

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to create 2 arrays of random integers in the range 1-6. But I keep getting the same numbers.

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    player1[i] = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
    player2[i] = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with the snippet posted. It should work as you expect. Maybe, some other issue somewhere else?

Comment: Can you also show us how you check that the 2 arrays are the same ?

Comment: This works as written, assuming player1 and player2 are properly initialized as _separate_ `int` arrays. You'll need to provide more detail. Are _all_ of the numbers the same, or are only corresponding numbers the same? Do you get the same number(s) from run to run?

Comment: Is the problem that you don't want the same number twice in the array?

Comment: sample o/p : 2 3
6 3
5 4
3 2
3 6

Comment: ahh... the problem is when I compare and print them out. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should return what's expected.

I would use this rather.

```
Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))
```

random number generated from above will be Min inclusive and Max Exclusive

Comment: why is that? sorry if it's obvious. i just started learning programming this week.

Comment: @JavaNoob it is one of standard way to do it, and if you want double,long you just need to change the typecast as Math.random() returns double values.

Comment: I find `random.nextInt(6) + 1` much easier to read than `Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))`. Also less casting, less arithmetic and less code.